# Existence Adjoint Operator: Boundedness?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, adjoint-operators

**Context**

This would make the check on the GNS construction much more simple.

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a merely linear operator $A:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$.

Suppose it has a formal adjoint:
$$\langle A^*\psi,\varphi\rangle=\langle\psi,A\varphi\rangle\quad(\varphi,\psi\in\mathcal{H})$$
*(Obviously, it must be unique!)*

Does it imply boundedness:
$$\|A\varphi\|\leq\|A\|\cdot\|\varphi\|$$
$$\|A^*\psi\|\leq\|A^*\|\cdot\|\psi\|$$

I guess not as one has only:
$$\|A\varphi\|=\sup_{\|\hat{\chi}\|=1}|\langle\hat{\chi},A\varphi\rangle|=\sup_{\|\hat{\chi}\|=1}|\langle A^*\hat{\chi},\varphi\rangle|
\\\leq\sup_{\|\hat{\chi}\|=1}\|A^*\hat{\chi}\|\cdot\|\varphi\|=\|A^*\|\cdot\|\varphi\|$$
$$\|A^*\psi\|=\sup_{\|\hat{\chi}\|=1}|\langle A^*\psi,\hat{\chi},\rangle|=\sup_{\|\hat{\chi}\|=1}|\langle\psi,A\hat{\chi}\rangle|
\\\leq\|\psi\|\cdot\sup_{\|\hat{\chi}\|=1}\|A\hat{\chi}\|=\|\psi\|\cdot\|A\|$$
*(So they must be either both bounded or both unbounded.)*

Is there an example where boundedness fails?

Besides, this is equivalent to the adjoint over Banach spaces satisfying a purely functional relation...

**Greetings**

Thanks to so many grate answers!! :)

Comment: You mean $\langle A^* \psi, \phi \rangle = \langle \psi, A \phi \rangle$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yep, thanks. ;) Corrected!

Comment: $A^\ast$ is a closed operator (why?), defined on all of $\mathcal{H}$. Hence $A^\ast$ is continuous. Hence $A^{\ast\ast}$ is continuous. But $A^{\ast\ast} = A$ (why?).

Comment: Got it, thanks! :)

Comment: This is true and is known as the [Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger%E2%80%93Toeplitz_theorem).

Comment: @NateEldredge: Hellinger-Toeplitz usually refers to symmetric operators but right they're all sort of equivalent... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify directly that $A$ is closed.

Assume $\{ x_n \}$ and $\{ Ax_{n}\}$ converge to $x$, $y$ respectively. Then, for all $z \in \mathcal{H}$,
$$
              (Ax_n, z) = (x_n, A^{\star}z)
             \implies (y,z)=(x,A^{\star}z)=(Ax,z)
             \implies y = Ax
$$

Comment: Nice and easy, thanks! :)

Comment: @Freeze_S : There's a nice theorem regarding this, too: If $A$ is densely defined, then $A$ is closable iff $A^{\star}$ is densely-defined.

Comment: Ah of course ^^ simply $A=A^{**}=\overline{A}$. *'dough'*

Comment: @Freeze_S : Good time to mention this: If $T_{f}x=\int fdEx$ for all $x$ such that $\int |f|^{2}d\|Ex\|^{2} < \infty$, then $T_{f}$ is closed densely defined with adjoint $T_{f}^{\star}=T_{\overline{f}}$ on the same domain. And $T_{f}$ is normal.

Comment: Yep the normal ones come with a whole package. *(One might be tempted to say the normal ones give a whole theory.)* ;)

Comment: TrialAndError, thank you so much again!!! :) *(We're just having the GNS construction in operator algebra. This unwinds the subject nicely.)*

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that for every $\psi \in \mathcal H$, the linear functionals
$\phi \to \langle \psi, A \phi \rangle$ are bounded.  Use the uniform boundedness principle...

Comment: Ah ok, please, let me check.

Comment: Ok so for $l_\hat{\chi}:=\langle\hat{\chi},A\varphi\rangle$ for all $\|\hat{\chi}\|=1$ one has $|l_{\hat{\chi}}(\varphi)|=\ldots\leq\|A^*\hat{\chi}\|\cdot\|\varphi\|$ and $\sup_{\|\hat{\chi}\|=1}|l_\hat{\chi}(\varphi)|=\ldots\leq\|A\varphi\|<\infty$ and therefore $\|A\|^2=\ldots=\sup_{\|\hat{\chi}\|=1}\|l_\hat{\chi}\|<\infty$.